# SwiftUI - How to add gestures conditionally according to some variables?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am building a drawing app where users can:

1. Add a background and images on a canvas.
2. Users can perform a magnification gesture on the canvas, depending on the current edit mode, it will either

   1. zoom in/out everything on the canvas
   2. zoom in/out the images only.
3. Users can also pan the canvas, moving everything in parallel.

Here is my first attempt:

```swift
struct Canvas: View {
    @State var zoomEverything = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            images // View that render images
            background // View that render the background
        }
        .gesture(gesturePanEverything().simultaneously(with: zoomEverything ? gestureZoomEverything() : gestureZoomImagesOnly()))
    }
    
    private func gestureZoomEverything() -> some Gesture {
        MagnificationGesture()
            .onChanged { value in updateBackgroundScale(value) }
            .onEnded { value in updateBackgroundScale(value)  }
    }
    
    private func gestureZoomImagesOnly() -> some Gesture {
        MagnificationGesture()
            .onChanged { value in updateImagesScale(value) }
            .onEnded { value in updateImagesScale(value) }
    }
    
    private func gesturePanEverything() -> some Gesture { DragGesture() }
    private func updateImagesScale(_ value: CGFloat) { /* ... */ }
    private func updateBackgroundScale(_ value: CGFloat) { /* ... */ }
    var images: some View { EmptyView() }
    var background: some View { EmptyView() }
}
```

(Detail logics are replaced by dummy codes, but I think it is enough for demonstrate the problem)

Unfortunately the compiler complained:

> Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'some Gesture' (result of 'Canvas.gestureZoomEverything()') and 'some Gesture' (result of 'Canvas.gestureZoomImagesOnly()')

I understand why this error happens - two function's return type are different, and the compiler cannot decide which one should be used, but I cannot find an elegant way to get rid of this error.

Comment: Why not pull the logic out of `.gesture()` and implement it in a computed variable or a function? Ternaries don't work for everything.